# Redirect output to a TextBox in PowerShell using XAML

Tags: powershell, xaml, redirect, textbox

I'm building a PowerShell script with a GUI using XAML. I'm calling a function (form a DLL file) that it's writing its output in the console, but I want to make it write in the TextBox instead. See image below to see what happens when I click on the button `CHECK DATA` which is calling the dummy method `set_Value` I've created to test.

[PS1-GUI Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g41Az.png)

> I've tried to use [redirections](https://www.windows10forums.com/articles/windows-powershell-tutorial-5-advanced-redirection.69/) with no success. I was only able to make it write to a file. I'm sure I'm missing something, but not sure what it is.

**XAML**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DataBase Export Import Tool" Height="469.28" Width="760" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode='NoResize'>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,-0.2,0.2">
        <Label Content="From Client" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="#006271" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Content="To Client" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="390,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="#006271" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Content="From Environment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="#006271" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Content="To Environment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="390,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="#006271" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Content="SQL Server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="#006271" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Name="prdSqlResult" Content="Server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="White" Foreground="#006271"/>
        <Label Content="SQL Server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="390,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="#006271" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Name="sqlResult" Content="Server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="565,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="White" Foreground="#006271"/>
        <Label Content="Database" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="#006271" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Name="prdDbResult" Content="Database" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="White" Foreground="#006271"/>
        <Label Content="Database" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="390,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="#006271" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Name="dbResult" Content="Database" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="565,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="170" Background="White" Foreground="#006271"/>

        <TextBox Name="OutputBox" Height="200" Width="720" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,100,0,0" />

        <Button Name="checkData" Content="Check Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,387,0,0" Width="220" BorderThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,-2.677" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Name="btndbe" Content="Run Database Export" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="268,387,0,0" Width="220" BorderThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,-2.677" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Name="btndbi" Content="Run Database Import" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="516,387,0,0" Width="220" BorderThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,-2.677" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="0">
        <ComboBox Name="comboFromClient" IsEditable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="194,10,0,0" Width="170">
            <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="0">
        <ComboBox Name="comboFromEnvironment" IsEditable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="194,45,0,0" Width="170">
            <ComboBoxItem ToolTip="This it tool tip for item 1">PRD</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>A</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>B</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>C</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="0">
        <ComboBox Name="comboToClient" IsEditable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="565,10,0,0" Width="170">
            <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>CN</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="0">
        <ComboBox Name="comboToEnvironment" IsEditable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="565,45,0,0" Width="170">
            <ComboBoxItem>A</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>B</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**PS1**

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework,WindowsBase,system.windows.forms
$XAML = [xml](Get-Content -Path "$PSSCriptRoot\GuiDataImportExport.xaml")
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 

#Dummy function to be able to get some output instead using the real method
function set-Value{    
    for($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++){        
        $sortie = $i | timestamp
        Write-Host $sortie
        Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

function timestamp { Process{"$(Get-Date): $_"} }

$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

$OutputBox = $Form.FindName("OutputBox")

$checkData.Add_Click({
   #this writes in the console
   set-Value

   #This writes in a file
   $OutputBox.AppendText((&{set-Value} *>> "$PSScriptRoot\log.log"))
})

$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Please let me know if you guys need more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need Text property.

```
$OutputBox.Text = set-Value
```

You will have to change `Write-Host` to `Write-Output` in your function.

Comment: Thanks, this works changing to `Write-Host` however, the result is shown once the process is completed, I'd need it showing in real time. Any idea?

Comment: @giannigb what do you mean under "real time"? You add the code to the event of button click. You should add another event listener that suits your needs.

Comment: What I mean is that the method output is currently only shown in the textBox when the method has ended running. So all the output shows in one shoot at the end of the execution. Hope I'm clearer now. Thanks